# How can i make settings activity like this picture below?

Tags: android, android-activity, preferenceactivity

[Image of activity I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4L8N9.jpg)

I have to create this type of Settings activity,**custom Switch**,**multiple Headers** . Please help me out.Suggest me perfect solution or some Tutorial. Thank you.

Comment: I haven't find perfect solution nor tutorial on google .

Comment: Tell where you are stuck and what is your problem is !! Stack-overflow is not a Spoon-feeding site..

Comment: You have to make custom layout for it.

Comment: here you can discuss any bug or issue regarding your source. If you need a complete code then this forum will not help you in this way.

Comment: Harsh, are you Prajapati ?

Comment: Kind of @NSPratik .
Why ?

Comment: @ChandrakantDvivedi if you know how to code this then tell me otherwise don't type this type of silly comments.Brainless creature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUOWNXGRc6g&list=PL2F07DBCDCC01493A

**Videos 54-58**

Replace the **Checkbox**es with **SwitchPreference**s

Comment: lemme know if it helped!

Comment: thank you @Andy I saw this before but I have to create that custom switch and custom Divider .that is my problem but some people don't suggest me solution instead of they all are screw my Question !!

Comment: tough living in this community